# Correct Self-Intersecting Polygons in Google-Maps React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, polygon, geojson, google-maps-react

I am working on my wildfire tracking app (firewild.netlify.app) and it's going well aside from the fact that my app is displaying ugly self-intersecting polygons. I am trying to find a way to stop this from happening.

Here is my current code, also props to the last stackOverflow answer related to this app for helping me render my polygons correctly. (user: x00)

```
/ This funciton reverses coordinates and makes them readable by GeoJSON
const coord_pair_to_latlng =  ([lng, lat]) => ({ lat, lng })

const convert_ring_coords = ring => ring.map(coord_pair_to_latlng)

const mapStyles = {
    margin: 30,
    width: '93.75%',
    height: '90%',
    border: '1px solid #3E1C18',
    display: 'inline-block'
};


class FireMap extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { fires: [] }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/f72ebe741e3b4f0db376b4e765728339_0.geojson')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ fires: data.features }))
  }

  displayFires = () => this.state.fires
    .filter(fire => fire.geometry !== null)
    .map(fire => fire.geometry.coordinates[0])
    .map(rings => <Polygon 
      paths = { rings.reduce((acc, ring) => acc.concat(convert_ring_coords(ring)), []) }
      fillColor     = "#BF5E4B"
      fillOpacity   = {0.45}
      strokeColor   = "#6B352A"
      strokeOpacity = {0.9}
      strokeWeight  = {1}
    />)


  render (){
    return (
      <div className="mapBox">
        <Map
          google        = {this.props.google}
          zoom          = {8}
          style         = {mapStyles}
          initialCenter = {{ lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4149 }}
        >
          {this.displayFires()}
        </Map>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any self intersecting polygons in that GeoJSON data: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kteLmrg1/). Is your processing combining the paths of separate polygons?

Comment: It is not combining polygons, but the fires are showing up with major topology errors I can't figure out how to correct. firewild.netlify.app this is how it currently is running on my machine. Why are they self intersecting? Something must be wrong with how I am drawing the polygons, or perhaps they are trying to connect from the last point back to the first?

Comment: I sliced the last coordinate from each prior to mapping the rings, which fixed some but not all of them.

Comment: @geocodezip I think that is correct, because when I try to use the slice method, I just noticed it deleted a lot of the polygons from the map.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem! Very simple fix, took the idea from Matthew Welch on Medium. Pushed the coords into an array to map each polygon, which fixed the issue of them "self-intersecting" which as @geocodezip suggested is probably because my displayFires function was trying to merge the polygons together. Thanks for help and thanks to Matthew Welch for the great article! (side note: he is using react-google-maps for his example, which is not the same as google-maps-react that I'm using.) Gonna work more on styling my app and adding new features.

https://medium.com/@dmw9400/using-geojson-with-google-maps-api-5127f7498a33

Here's my updated displayFires function:

```
  displayFires() {
    return this.state.fires.map (fire => {
      let coordinates = fire.geometry.coordinates[0][0]
      let coordArr = []
      coordinates.map(coordinate => coordArr.push({lat:coordinate[1], lng:coordinate[0]} ))
      return ( 
        <Polygon 
          paths = {coordArr}
          fillColor     = "#BF5E4B"
          fillOpacity   = {0.45}
          strokeColor   = "#6B352A"
          strokeOpacity = {0.9}
          strokeWeight  = {1}
        />
      )
    })
  }
```

Thanks again to everyone who's helped me so far! @x00 @geocodezip and Matthew Welch on Medium